# dotnet run exits unexpectedly when loading sqlite extension

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core

I'm connecting to sqlite db (using `System.Data.SQLite`) and attempting to load an extension (json1) in dotnet core on a linux machine:

```
using var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=:memory:");
connection.Open();
connection.EnableExtensions(true);
connection.LoadExtension("<path-to-project>/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/publish/runtimes/linux-x64/native/SQLite.Interop.dll", "sqlite3_json_init");
// statements to query the db
```

The above code works fine when using `dotnet publish` and running the resulting dll. However running the same exact code with `dotnet run` exits (with code 0) on the line where it's loading the extension. None of the subsequent code is executed. There are no errors shown in the console. Using different verbosity levels with `dotnet run` doesn't provide any additional clues. I tried launching the program and breakpointing (with `justMyCode` set to `false`) and was not able to get any more details either.

I understand that `LoadExtension` eventually calls [`dlopen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) to load the dynamic library. What causes this code to halt unexpectedly when executed through `dotnet run`?

Comment: So you launched the program in the debugger? The debugger should show the exact exception causing the program to exit.

Comment: There is nothing indicating an error or exceptions. It is as if the program exited successfully (but it didn't actually run to the end).

Comment: Did you configure the debugger to stop on exceptions?

Comment: Yes, it's configured to stop on all exceptions. As noted in the question, the code is working when run as a dll so it must be something about using `dotnet run`.